# nginx blocks outgoing requests

Tags: django, nginx, devops

The situation:
I launched django and nginx via docker-compose on ubuntu vps hosting. nginx supports ports 80 and 443. The project opens by domain and redirects to https.

Problem:
Endpoints that send requests to other servers (to remote APIs) do not work. After sending, there is always a waiting timeout.

Here are some settings:
#nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    upstream app {
        server backend:8000;
    }
    server {
    listen 80;
    server_name eternitydigital.ru;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name eternitydigital.ru;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/certs/cert.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/private.key;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        }
    }
}
```

#Dockerfile nginx

```
FROM nginx:1.10.2

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

#docker-compose

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  django_app:
    build: ./django
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    image: backend
    container_name: backend

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/ssl/cert.crt:/etc/nginx/ssl/certs/cert.crt
      - ./nginx/ssl/private.key:/etc/nginx/ssl/private/private.key
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - django_app
    image: nginx
    container_name: nginx
```

P.S. At first there were more settings, but I have not been able to fix the problem for 2 days, so I removed a lot of things to at least make it work

What did you find out:

- requests/responses are successful directly from the system via curl
- I raised the same docker-compose on my Windows, all the endpoints work as they should
- the most interesting thing: if you build on the hosting not through docker-compose, but only django without nginx, then everything works as it should

#Dockerfile django

```
FROM python:3.11.7-slim-bullseye
RUN pip install --upgrade pip


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBUTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD python manage.py migrate --noinput && python manage.py loaddata initial_data && gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8000 E_Service.wsgi:application
```

A broken request:

```
 response = requests.post(
         
'http://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/address',
            headers={
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Token ' + ADDRESS_HINTS_API_TOKEN,
            }, 
            json={
                'query': query,
                "locations": [{ "country": "Россия" }],
                'count': '8'
            },
        )
```

Comment: `other servers` are they public servers or some of yours? Show example of an URL which does not work. Nginx should have no effect on outgoing requests if I understand your description correctly. And please show your django container DOCKERFILE.

Comment: My server sends a request to the remote API for address hints.
I have completed the question. As I said, if I lift this container without nginx, then when contacting `http://domen:8000` the endpoints are functioning correctly

Comment: Please show log records where you indicated timeouts. Also you have a typo here `PYTHONDONTWRITEBUTECODE` - B**Y**TE

Comment: Here is the error log from django

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/httpx/_transports/default.py", line 84, in map_httpcore_exceptions
backend       |     raise mapped_exc(message) from exc
backend       | httpx.ConnectTimeout

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the mtu. I redefined it in docker-compose and everything started working correctly. On my server, the default was 1500

```
networks:
    default:
      driver: bridge
      driver_opts:
        com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1450
```